# Passing a value between a ViewController and NavigationController inside a TapBarController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I would like to pass a bool value from a viewcontroller to navigation controller inside a tabbarcontroller. Because I need to show a different view in accordance to the passed value.

By the way I couldn't pass the value through a code below,

```
// ViewController 
let navigationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigation") as! NavigationController 

navigationVC.pass = true
```

But I couldn't get the value. Is it because a tabbarcontroller between the ViewController and NavigationController?

Comment: How does storyboard look like: [TabBarController[[ViewController1]->[NavigationController]],[ViewController2][ViewController3]] ?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSUserDefaults then you can reach data all pages
For setting,

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true,forKey: "state")
```

or

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false,forKey: "state")
```

For accessing

```
let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("state")
```